# Magento 2 Mail User subscribed on emai id

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I want to send email id of newly subscriber user to admin mail, below is my module code .

mail is working fine when new subscriber is added but I am unable to get **`subscriber email id`** **helper/data.php**

**app/code/Stack/NewsletterNotify/etc/email_templates.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="newsletter_subscription_success_admin_email_template" label="Subscription Notification to Admin" file="subscr_notify_admin.html" type="html" module="Stack_NewsletterNotify" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/Stack/NewsletterNotify/etc/frontend/events.xml and the following content in it:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="newsletter_subscriber_save_after">
        <observer name="newsletter_subscriber_save_after_event" instance="Stack\NewsletterNotify\Observer\NotifyAdmin"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**file app/code/Stack/NewsletterNotify/Observer/NotifyAdmin.php with the following content:**

```
<?php
namespace Stack\NewsletterNotify\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class NotifyAdmin implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {
    private $logger;
    private $helper;

    public function __construct(\Stack\NewsletterNotify\Helper\Data $helper, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $subscriberEmail = $event->getSubscriber()->getSubscriberEmail();
        $subscriberStatus = $event->getSubscriber()->getSubscriberStatus();
        if ($subscriberStatus == 1) {
            $this->helper->notifyAdmin($subscriberEmail);
        }
    }

}
```

**file Data.php under app/code/Stack/NewsletterNotify/Helper and put the following content:**

```
<?php

namespace Stack\NewsletterNotify\Helper;

class Data {
    protected $_logger;
    protected $_storeManager;
    private $scopeConfig;
    private $transportBuilder;
    private $inlineTranslation;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation, \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {

        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function notifyAdmin($email) {
        try {
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

            $this->transportBuilder
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier('newsletter_subscription_success_admin_email_template')
                    ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
                    ->setTemplateVars(['subscriber' => $this])
                    ->setFrom(array('email' => '{sender email}', 'name' => '{sender name}'))
                    ->addTo({admin email}, {admin name});
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();

            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore(true)->getId();
    }

}
```

> Content of mailer html

Update: Sample content for **subscr_notify_admin.html** file

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Subscription Notification to Admin"}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/footer_template\"":"Email Footer Template",
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/header_template\"":"Email Header Template"
} @-->


{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

{{trans "A new user has subscribed to our newsletter."}}

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you @user1799722?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app/code/Stack/NewsletterNotify/Helper/Data.php file, please replace the function notifyAdmin() as below:

```
public function notifyAdmin($email) {
    try {
        $to = {admin email};
        $from = ['email' => '{sender email}', 'name' => '{sender name}'];
        $templateOptions = ['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->getStoreId()];
        $templateVars = ['subscriberemail' => $email];
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

        $this->transportBuilder
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier('newsletter_subscription_success_admin_email_template')
                    ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                    ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                    ->setFrom($from)
                    ->addTo($to);
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();

            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

and then call the template variable **subscriberemail** in the email template as mentioned below:

```
{{var subscriberemail}}
```

Please let me know if you have any other question.